# On proper use of Waves L2

Tags: waves

Should I use the L2 plugin as a limiter before or after rendering a project?I mean,which would be better for the project to run nicely?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your tools, workflow and what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Always run it as the very last plugin in the chain.

Even if you are going to be sending the mix away for mastering, setting both threshold & out ceiling to -0.3 will just prevent overs.

If even at those settings it's too hot, then pull back the entire mix earlier in the chain.
If levels are too low, you **can** use it to lift the overall levels, but I wouldn't. I'd compensate earlier in the workflow.

If you're attempting to do the mastering yourself, then there are two ways to go.

- Mix & master all in one.
  These days there's no real loss if you have to come back to the project to remaster later, it's all saved & can be restored in a few seconds.
- Mix first, master later.
  I'd still use it to just hold any slight overs. Then come back later & use it on the final stereo mix to do your mastering.